# Some properties implied from the definition of semidirect product.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

**Problem:** Let $G$ be an inner semidirect product of $N$ by $H$. For each element of $H$, denote $\theta_h \colon N \rightarrow N$ is a map defined by $\theta_h (x) = h x h^{-1}, \forall x \in N$. Prove that:

1. $\theta_h$ is a isomorphism of $N$ for all $h \in H$.
2. The map $\theta \colon H \rightarrow \text{Aut}(N)$ defined by $\theta(h) = \theta_h$ for all $h \in H$ is a group homomorphism.
3. All element $g \in G$ can be written uniquely in the form $g=xh$ in which $x \in N$ and $h \in H$.
4. Suppose $g_1 = x_1 h_1$ and $g_2 = x_2 h_2$ with $x_1,x_2 \in N$ and $h_1,h_2 \in H$. Then $g_1 g_2 = (x_1 h_1) (x_2 h_2) = x_1 \theta_{h_1} (x_2) h_1 h_2$.

**My proof:**

1. $\forall x,y \in N, \theta_h (xy) = h xy h^{-1} = h x h^{-1} h y h^{-1} = \theta_h (x) \theta_h (y)$. So $\theta_h$ is a group homomorphism. For each $h \in H$, we have the map $\theta_{h^{-1}}$ with $\theta_{h^{-1}} (x) = (h^{-1})x(h^{-1})^{-1} = h^{-1} x h$, implies $\theta_h \theta_{h^{-1}} (x) = h h^{-1} x h h^{-1} = x$. Hence $\theta_h$ is a group isomorphism.
2. $\forall h, h' \in H$, we have $\theta (h h') (x) = \theta_{h h'} (x) = h h' x (h h')^{-1} = h h' x h'^{-1} h^{-1} = h \theta_{h'} (x) h^{-1} = \theta_h (\theta_{h'} (x)) = (\theta_h \theta_{h'}) (x)$. This follows that $\theta$ is a group homomorphism.
3. $G$ is an inner semidirect product of $N$ by $H$. So we have $N,H$ are subgroup of $G$, $G=NH$, $N \triangleleft G$ and $N \cap H = \{1\}$. Is that enough to conclude that all element of $G$ can be written quiquely in the form $g=xh$, $x \in N$, $h \in H$?
4. We have $g_1 g_2 = (x_1 h_1)(x_2 h_2) = x_1 h_1 x_2 h_2 = x_1 h_1 x_2 h_1^{-1} h_1 h_2$, this is the mupltiplication in $G$, so it associative, $= x_1 (h_1 x_2 h_1^{-1}) h_1 h_2 = x_1 \theta_{h_1} (x_2) h_1 h_2$.

Please check my proof and show me some hint to prove that $3$. This problem could be very easy to many people, it seems like the definition but I have to prove this. Thank all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To (3), yes, but you should give the proof. If $n_{i} \in N$, $h_{i} \in H$, and $n_{1} h_{1} = n_{2} h_{2}$, then $N \ni n_{2}^{-1} n_{1} = h_{2} h_{1}^{-1} \in H$, and thus $n_{2}^{-1} n_{1} = 1 =  h_{2} h_{1}^{-1}$, as $N \cap H = \{ 1 \}$.

As to (4),
$$
(x_1 h_1) (x_2 h_2) = x_{1} h_{1} x_{2} (h_{1}^{-1} h_{1}) h_{2} = x_{1} (h_{1} x_{2} h_{1}^{-1}) h_{1} h_{2}= \dots
$$

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are fine (maybe in (2) specify that $\theta_h(1)=1$)

Hint (3): Since $G=NH$ by definition certainly every $g \in G$ can be written as $g=nh$ for some $n \in N$, $h\in H$. The part that needs to be proved is the "uniquely". So suppose that $g=n_1 h_1$ and $g=n_2 h_2$, can you prove that $n_1 = n_2$ and $h_1=h_2$?

Hint (4): what is the definition of an *inner* semidirect product? You are right, that is the definition of the operation... of an *outer* semidirect product. In the end, the two notions coincide, and what the exercise is asking you is to do a step of the proof of this fact.